# Get ID of Clicked Link & Change Its Class

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I put together a single-page "web app" using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. There's 3 links, when a user clicks a link it shows content for that link and hides content for the other links. When a link is clicked it should change to bold but it doesn't. I did some research and found that I should use:

```
// Bold selected link
this.className = "selectedLink";
```

within my function to get the clicked link's ID but it is not working. Why can't I get the ID of the clicked link within my function? I want to keep my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript separate.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYEUV/

```
<style>
.selectedLink {
    font-weight: bold;  
}
</style>

<p><a href="#" id="linkPage1" class="selectedLink">Example Page 1</a> | <a href="#" id="linkPage2">Example Page 2</a> | <a href="#" id="linkPage3">Example Page 3</a></p>

<div id="page1">
<h1>Example Page 1</h1>
<p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>

<div id="page2">
<h1>Example Page 2</h1>
<p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>

<div id="page3">
<h1>Example Page 3</h1>
<p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>

<script>
var pages = [page1, page2, page3];

 // Displays page and hides all other pages
function goToPage(pageID) {
    console.log(pageID);
    // Display page
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        if (pageID == pages[i].id) {
            // Show page
            pages[i].style.display = "block";

            // Bold selected link
            this.className = "selectedLink";
        } else {
            console.log(pages[i]);
            // Hide page
            pages[i].style.display = "none";

            // Unbold unselected link
            this.className = "selectedLink";
        }
    }
}

linkPage1.onclick = function () {
    goToPage("page1");
};

linkPage2.onclick = function () {
    goToPage("page2");
};

linkPage3.onclick = function () {
    goToPage("page3");
};

goToPage("page1");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you were having setting the className is related to how the function is being called.

In your event handler for the click, the `this` context is the anchor.  However, when you call `goToPage()` the `this` context is `window`.

You could remedy that by changing the call to `goToPage` to

```
goToPage.call(this, "page1");
```

However, you then bump into the next issue which is that `this` now refers to the recently clicked anchor.  Because of that, there was no way, with your current logic, to remove the `selectedLink` class.

The quick solution is to refactor your code a bit to match the pattern you have already established by using the pages array.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/ZYEUV/5/)

Script:

```
var pages = [page1, page2, page3];
var links = [linkPage1, linkPage2, linkPage3];

// Displays page and hides all other pages
function goToPage(pageID, evt) {
    console.log(pageID);
    // Display page
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        if (pageID == pages[i].id) {
            // Show page
            pages[i].style.display = "block";

            // Bold selcted link
            links[i].className = "selectedLink";
        } else {
            console.log(pages[i]);
            // Hide page
            pages[i].style.display = "none";

            // Unbold unselected link
            links[i].className = "";
        }
    }
}
```

**Alternate Approach**

By changing your markup a bit, you can reduce some of the repetition in your code and simplify adding new pages.

In your HTML, add a data-page attribute to your links:

```
<a href="#" id="linkPage1" class="selectedLink" data-page="page1">…</a>
```

With that change, your script can be refactored to something like this:

```
// List of links with a data-page attribute
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-page]");
var pages = {};

function clickHandler() {
    var page = this.dataset.page;

    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
        links[i].className = "";
        pages[links[i].dataset.page].style.display = "none";
    }

    this.className = "selectedLink";
    pages[page].style.display = "block";
}

// Setup handlers in a loop (maybe use addEventListener here instead)
// Store map of pages by id
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    links[i].onclick = clickHandler;
    pages[links[i].dataset.page] = document.getElementById(links[i].dataset.page);
}

// Call the click handler with the context of the link to initialize
links[0].onclick.call(links[0]);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/ZYEUV/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You miss something :)
http://jsfiddle.net/ZYEUV/3/

JS:

```
var pages = [page1, page2, page3];
var links = [linkPage1, linkPage2, linkPage3];

 // Displays page and hides all other pages
function goToPage(pageID) {
    console.log(pageID);
    // Display page
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        if (pageID == pages[i].id) {
            // Show page
            pages[i].style.display = "block";


            // Bold selcted link
            links[i].className = "selectedLink";

        } else {
            console.log(pages[i]);
            // Hide page
            pages[i].style.display = "none";

            // Unbold unselected link
            links[i].className = "";
        }
    }
}

linkPage1.onclick = function () {
    goToPage("page1");
};

linkPage2.onclick = function () {
    goToPage("page2");
};

linkPage3.onclick = function () {
    goToPage("page3");
};

goToPage("page1");
```